# Xcode6-Beta4 Build fails for device, works for simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

After installing the latest betas, my app builds when I select the simulator but fails when I try to build for device. The biggest clue I can point to is that when it tries to build one of my linked frameworks (GPUImage), the number of files is doubled it tells me it's building (326 instead of 163), and the error only comes up when (it appears to be) building the framework the second time. I can't identify any differences in settings between the simulator and the device, but maybe I'm not looking in the right place. Any tips would be appreciated.

My question is: If changing the scheme from device to simulator causes different behavior, and a reduced test case does not exhibit the same symptoms, where in Xcode can I compare schemes for differences? AFAICT, there aren't any in the "Edit Schemes" sheet.

The specific error is that there's no public @interface for UIImage that defines a selector initWithData: - a bogus error.

Xcode6-Beta4, OSX 10.10

Comment: This looks like a bug that you should report to Apple. After all, it's a beta version of the software.

Comment: when I created a sample project and linked the library, it worked, so I can't reduce the test case. If I can, I'll report it.

Comment: it turns out that when I plug my device and it goes from "iOS Device" to "Majd Taby's iPhone", it builds 163 files only, but it still fails. Hmph, the price of using beta software...

Comment: Try deleting the derived data folder, and starting from scratch. Did you somehow link a library twice (never saw that though)?

Comment: Turns out it was a problem with even a plain, vanilla project (which xcode6-beta4 doesn't generate correctly, so I had to generate it in the stable version of Xcode). Vending GPUImage into the project doesn't build on my device, but switching to cocoa pods fixed the problem for me.